# Encoded path in MySQL database

Tags: google-maps

I have encoded the paths of several polylines using `google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath()` and want to store them in a MySQL table.

**Problem:** Before storing them into the table, I drew out the polylines as shown in the top half of the image below. However, after storing them into the table, retrieveing them and drawing again, the path seems to have changed! What happened?

[image]

**Additional Info**: I notice that if i were to write the freshly encoded path to `console.log`, copy from the console log and use this copied path to draw a new polyline, the polyline gets distorted at certain areas, just like what happened after using the encoded path that was retrieved from the database!

---

### Update

**Polyline using freshly encoded path**

[image]

**JS Code**

```
encoded_path = google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath(path);
console.log(encoded_path);

decoded_path = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encoded_path);

var polyOptions = {
            strokeColor: "#970E04" , 
            strokeOpacity: 1.0 , 
            strokeWeight: 2 , 
            path: decoded_path , 
            clickable: false,
            map: map
    }
polyline = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
```

**Encoded path from console.log**

> axwaGtbcqL`BgArBmAjCcBlBcCnBeChB_BrAmAxByBjCoCkAqBmByCu@qA[i@~BmAdAq@FEzAqAvAsA|@{@DCr@{@DIjAuA|@cAz@}@~AeB\[LZxAjDJINM|AkAxAxCfAw@g@jAeBpEOr@Ox@CTeAlMM~AYhDc@pE_AtHGj@m@`Gm@dHa@hFaAbM_AfJ]jDAlA{Hhv@eAdFy@bCcBpEeBzDyArDu@`E_AnFs@|Fq@fGKtKaEqCgBmB_GmFcJaM}@nBg@BbA}CpAaEvAoEnGyOvDuPDSPYAIIMMMGOMMIIKKKQIMIKIKa@gAQ_@Q[CCY_@OSQYQQOOSMSOa@]g@g@UWSUYm@Uk@]qAKe@Ia@I_@Iy@Es@C_AAw@A]Ca@G[Qy@GSKa@M]M_@Qa@M]IOGKQSGIIG}@w@{AgAiAaAWSUOWOQIMEKCICOGMCKEQC_DuA?GbByB\_@~GaIxCgDl@s@bBkBnBcBzCqC`Ai@pCmA^mAd@qA

---

**Polyline using path retrieved from database**

[image]

**Value stored in column `VARCHAR(255)`**

*Copied using Navicat*

> axwaGtbcqL`BgArBmAjCcBlBcCnBeChB_BrAmAxByBjCoCkAqBmByCu@qA[i@~BmAdAq@FEzAqAvAsA|@{@DCr@{@DIjAuA|@cAz@}@~AeB[LZxAjDJINM|AkAxAxCfAw@g@jAeBpEOr@Ox@CTeAlMM~AYhDc@pE_AtHGj@m@`Gm@dHa@hFaAbM_AfJ]jDAlA{Hhv@eAdFy@bCcBpEeBzDyArDu@`E_AnFs@|Fq@fGKtKaEqCgBmB_GmFcJaM}@

---

**Polyline using path retrieved from database with `VARCHAR(1000)`**

[image]

**Value stored in column `VARCHAR(1000)`**

*Copied using Navicat*

> axwaGtbcqL`BgArBmAjCcBlBcCnBeChB_BrAmAxByBjCoCkAqBmByCu@qA[i@~BmAdAq@FEzAqAvAsA|@{@DCr@{@DIjAuA|@cAz@}@~AeB[LZxAjDJINM|AkAxAxCfAw@g@jAeBpEOr@Ox@CTeAlMM~AYhDc@pE_AtHGj@m@`Gm@dHa@hFaAbM_AfJ]jDAlA{Hhv@eAdFy@bCcBpEeBzDyArDu@`E_AnFs@|Fq@fGKtKaEqCgBmB_GmFcJaM}@nBg@BbA}CpAaEvAoEnGyOvDuPDSPYAIIMMMGOMMIIKKKQIMIKIKa@gAQ_@Q[CCY_@OSQYQQOOSMSOa@]g@g@UWSUYm@Uk@]qAKe@Ia@I_@Iy@Es@C_AAw@A]Ca@G[Qy@GSKa@M]M_@Qa@M]IOGKQSGIIG}@w@{AgAiAaAWSUOWOQIMEKCICOGMCKEQC_DuA?GbByB\_@~GaIxCgDl@s@bBkBnBcBzCqC`Ai@pCmA^mAd@qA

---

**Polyline by decoding the encoded path written to console.log**

[image]

**JS Code**

```
  //encoded path copied from console.log output from the very first code in post
    encoded_path = 'axwaGtbcqLBgArBmAjCcBlBcCnBeChB_BrAmAxByBjCoCkAqBmByCu@qA[i@~BmAdAq@FEzAqAvAsA|@{@DCr@{@DIjAuA|@cAz@}@~AeB\[LZxAjDJINM|AkAxAxCfAw@g@jAeBpEOr@Ox@CTeAlMM~AYhDc@pE_AtHGj@m@Gm@dHa@hFaAbM_AfJ]jDAlA{Hhv@eAdFy@bCcBpEeBzDyArDu@E_AnFs@|Fq@fGKtKaEqCgBmB_GmFcJaM}@nBg@BbA}CpAaEvAoEnGyOvDuPDSPYAIIMMMGOMMIIKKKQIMIKIKa@gAQ_@Q[CCY_@OSQYQQOOSMSOa@]g@g@UWSUYm@Uk@]qAKe@Ia@I_@Iy@Es@C_AAw@A]Ca@G[Qy@GSKa@M]M_@Qa@M]IOGKQSGIIG}@w@{AgAiAaAWSUOWOQIMEKCICOGMCKEQC_DuA?GbByB\_@~GaIxCgDl@s@bBkBnBcBzCqCAi@pCmA^mAd@qA';
decoded_path = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encoded_path);

var polyOptions = {
            strokeColor: "#970E04" , 
            strokeOpacity: 1.0 , 
            strokeWeight: 2 , 
            path: decoded_path , 
            clickable: false,
            map: map
    }
polyline = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
```

---

**Path that did not work correctly as well**

I notice that there are newlines in the middle of these encoded strings? Also, the encoded string splits the line of code into 2 lines, causing the error checking system in my editor to show an alert.

**JS Code (Malformed)**

> encoded_path = '{traGxcspLaIkFvAwH}BgA{EzEjCgJmEwBmDvGoHpAkLQpAqGyF_CbCuH^}FlDwEo
>   Cyn@y@g[yL{c@wb@e`@sG@kHgEaBiJ}EiHzMwLdFga@{U{KoZoZhH{e@hh@~RlBgJ{AgMrAkQrD[rCl@pNmAhJeCgDhQdGlItBpQbTb@`EdQoBtMaJzSoE`f@bMzLlHRj@lHrFhCnHrNvAk@qBeOpAcAlRvCfEgQt@oB_JeBmTmL}DqJl@qHbCmEzFc]xr@nT|IoKf@`RlGdFtCuMpEzAbS}[qGe{@dOsEnGjZhInDrHwIjEdH_OtdAf@~WnM`F~AyN_DgEzh@nKgTvVbBrNoZvB_SvLwGfJwT~w@wG?gBzB?xFdAt@xFn@bBve@?nPoKv[kGwBsCdGoCtBwFoBwCfFcBvBoArDsC]{AxA';

**Encoded Path**

> {traGxcspLaIkFvAwH}BgA{EzEjCgJmEwBmDvGoHpAkLQpAqGyF_CbCuH^}FlDwEo
>   Cyn@y@g[yL{c@wb@e`@sG@kHgEaBiJ}EiHzMwLdFga@{U{KoZoZhH{e@hh@~RlBgJ{AgMrAkQrD[rCl@pNmAhJeCgDhQdGlItBpQbTb@`EdQoBtMaJzSoE`f@bMzLlHRj@lHrFhCnHrNvAk@qBeOpAcAlRvCfEgQt@oB_JeBmTmL}DqJl@qHbCmEzFc]xr@nT|IoKf@`RlGdFtCuMpEzAbS}[qGe{@dOsEnGjZhInDrHwIjEdH_OtdAf@~WnM`F~AyN_DgEzh@nKgTvVbBrNoZvB_SvLwGfJwT~w@wG?gBzB?xFdAt@xFn@bBve@?nPoKv[kGwBsCdGoCtBwFoBwCfFcBvBoArDsC]{AxA

Comment: Updated the post, wonder why the 2 encoded path before and after storage is different

Comment: You are storing your data in a VARCHAR(255) column ... the concatenated data seems to be 255 characters long. Hmm, I have an inkling what this could be. :)

Comment: I corrected the `VARCHAR(255)` to `VARCHAR(1000)` and repopulated the table so the values are not truncated. The resulting polyline is still incorrect... updated original post with encoded path from `VARCHAR(1000)` column. The differences between the retrieved and as-encoded path is that the as-encoded path have a newline after \

Comment: Hmm, strange. I don't know what encoding format is being used here....

Comment: The encoding format used is http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm.html and the encoding method doc is at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry.html#Encoding

Comment: What happens if you decode it and dump the data? Do the coordinates match?

Comment: Do you mean if I decode the as-encoded data? Yes, all the correctly drawn polylines had the original coordinates encoded, then decoded before drawing them.

Comment: I escaped the 2 slash in the encoded data copied from console.log, decoded them and now its closer to the correct polyline, but not quite! Wondering if console.log stripped away anything

Comment: Other encoded paths that contain no slashes to escape, did not draw correctly as well...

Comment: @Nyxynyx, the output from console.log may still have had slashes interpreted prior to writing out. Try this: `console.log(encoded_path.replace(/\\/g,"\\\\"))`, then compare that to the prior output of console.log. You'll likely find more than 2 slashes.

Comment: @Justin Great, the polylines are drawn properly now!

Comment: @Nyxynyx, see my answer below for a couple ways of handling this issue.

Comment: Polylines can exceed the limit of even VARCHAR(1000) try using TEXT. It should work without having need to escape '\' because they come escaped by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slashes in the string literal returned by `encodePath()` are being interpreted prior to write, whether the write is to screen or to database.

What I would do is escape the slashes at the earliest possible point:

```
encoded_path = google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath(path);
encoded_path = encoded_path.replace(/\\/g,"\\\\");
```

This should ensure that the string written to the database (or log) is correct, and you shouldn't have to do anything special on the read.

Alternatively, you can escape the slashes right before passing the string into another medium, such as just prior to your AJAX call or, as mentioned in the comments, in the `console.log()` method call.